# Form button that calls a python function

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Form button that calls a python function

Hello everyone!
I expose you my problem, if you could help me, I would be grateful to you!
I have a page with only one button inside of a python shape:

```
<form action = "http://localhost:5000/updateDB" method = "POST">
  <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
...
{% with success = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["success"]) %}
  {% if success %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for s in success %}
      <li>{{ s }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

and the python function is as follows:

```
@app.route('/updateDB',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def updateDB():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      log = updateDB()
      if log == 0
          flash(u'Success','success')
      return render_template("result.html")
```

But it does not work, it does not recall the function and, consequently, it does not print the message. What am I doing wrong?
I can only use python, flask, html, css and javascript (it's a school project)

Answer (score 0):

For one you are missing a : in your if statement, it should be

```
if log == 0:
    flash(u'Success','success')
    return render_template("result.html")
```

secondly, calling your function updateDB() in itself will cause a

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Excuse me, then I make a clarification just to be correct: I put an approximate code, because I'm not sure that you can make a form in this way, so I wanted a suggestion :)
In fact, in my code there are the ":" and the function is called in another way.